# HTML5 - Play a lengthy video only for a specified time without video editing. Any method will be welcomed

Tags: html, video, video-streaming, html5-video

I have a myvideo.mp4 of 3 mins (or of any length)

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
 <source src="myvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Can I be able to play this myvideo.mp4 of 3 mins for only 20 secs(or 1 min/2 min). The purpose of this question is that, I have no.of.videos where each video should be displayed for only a specified amount of time (in seconds or minutes) based on kind of user-login on the project i am working on.

I also would encourage any APIs or developed open source tools, or any solution that may solve my problem. The main output should reflect in a HTML video frame.

**NOTE:** no page refresh with timer. Because the user who watches the demo video (ie, the aim of this question) will have to submit a request to watch the full video)

--- **UPDATED** ---

Taking 3 mins video for example and when i set #t=30,60 as src="myvideo.mp4#t=30,60" (plays 30 secs), the video plays and pauses the video as specified. But the viewer can be able to resume the video again. That doesnt solves my problem.

The solution i am looking for is, I want the media player (the video window's) on the html webpage seek time itself as 30 secs !!

I believe you guys understand my problem statement.

Comment: can you try using timeupdate event ? like 
// event
video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function(){
    // check whether time passed 1 minutes,
    // current time is given in seconds
    if(this.currentTime >= 1 * 60) {
        this.pause();
    }
});
inside the if call a  pop up for to submit a request to watch full video.let me whehter this is the logic you are looking for.

Comment: I just dont wanted the video to start at a time and pause at a time. The request of the full video, i will be performing in a different way. Kindly see the first answer by @1957classic , i have replied with a comment. kindly read that and provide a reply

Answer (score 1):

This should start a video at 30 seconds and end it at 60.

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
 <source src="myvideo.mp4#t=30,60" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: the play and stop with specified time works. The result i am searching for is, 3 mins video for example and, when i set #t=30,60, I want the media player (the video window's) seek time itself as 30 secs !! because with the method suggested by you can again be resumed by the viewer. My aim isnt satisfied. I believe now you understood my issue clearly.